# Laravel Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, guzzle

I've installed the client and I did an update using *composer dump autoload* but I still end up with the same error. After installing via composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0 in the projects directory.

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Why isn' it working and why is it even referencing the wrong directory?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're going to want to get acquainted with PHP [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Most files in Laravel are namespaced. Calls to functions within a namespace start within that namespace, with two exceptions:

If you start the class name with a `\`, that tells PHP to start at the root-level namespace:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Or, you can put:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

at the top of the file (you'll see a *lot* of these already throughout Laravel's default files) and then do

```
$client = new Client();
```

Answer (score 4):

You might have not installed guzzle.

Run `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` to install it