# Guzzle not found. API request for client token grant

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

I'm trying to create **Laravel** as a `API server`

I'm trying to follow [Laravel Passport Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport).
I set up the basic components that I will use.

I'm using [Insomia](https://insomnia.rest/) and [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test my `API` calls.

So here is the thing. When I test `http://localhost:8000/oauth/token`. It works fine.

Configuration:

> **HEADERS**

`content-type | application/json`

> **BODY** : multipart

```
grant_type:     password
client_id:      my-client_id
client_secret:  my-client_secret
username:       my-username
password:       my-password
```

This configuration works fine and it throws me an `access_token`.

But when I try to put it on my `controller` and use `Guzzle`. So I make an route in my `route/api.php` and create `Route::post('login', 'Api/AuthController@login')` and also I create the `Api/AuthController`.

Heres what in my `Api/AuthController` based on [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client):

**NOTE:** I also install the `Guzzle` in my composer.

By using this commands on my terminal `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`, `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`. I see the guzzle in my `composer.json` file.

```
  $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

  $response = $http->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'client_id' => 'my-client_id',
      'client_secret' => 'my-client_secret',
      'username' => request('username'),
      'password' => request('password'),
      'scope' => '',
    ],
  ]);

  return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Configuration:

> **HEADERS**

`content-type | application/json`

> **BODY** : multipart

```
username:       my-username
password:       my-password
```

Another thing I tried is to put my `controller function` in my route directly but it throws the same output.

**ERROR/OUTPUT:**

(1) `$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;` // On my controller this throws an error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

(2) `$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;` // On my controller this throws an error:

> This request time takes forever. // It took me 500+ seconds and I cancel the request

(3) I put the `use Guzzle\Client;` and use it like `$http = new Client;`

> This still request takes forever.

(4) I tried the 3rd part and put `$http = new Client();`

> Still request takes forever.

**QUESTION**

How is there any other way to make a `client grant token` to may an `API` request.

I tried this following [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870356/laravel-class-app-http-controllers-guzzlehttp-client-not-found) and [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227080/laravel-class-guzzlehttp-client-not-found) but still no luck.

**LOGS**

```
[2019-09-25 00:38:06] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\GuzzleHttp\\Client' not found at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\AuthController.php:11)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\AuthController->login(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('login', Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\AuthController), 'login')
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php(59): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 60, '1')
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\aa\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#33 {main}
"}
```

Comment: Your (2) is seems correct. I think the issue is `http://localhost:8000` part. How about inject it through env file using: `env("APP_URL")`. If you visit `http://localhost:8000` in your browser does it work? If you use `php artisan serve` 
 maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19944781/4705339). Lastly take a look at [both answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44172818/registering-user-with-laravel-passport) - this is how I achieved the similar thing years ago

Comment: `content-type: application/json` in your headers and `multipart` body do not seem compatible

Comment: @senty I tried your to put it im my `env('APP_URL')` but still takes forever

Comment: @Phil the 1st one works well on `content: application/json`. Still I will try to put it in json format

Comment: @Phil still no luck

Comment: What do the logs for your `localhost:8000` service say?

Comment: @Phil where can I see the logs?

Comment: @phil I edited my question you can see the logs

Comment: @Doggo how did you managed to work? Any solution?

Comment: @VijayRana i used https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client this instead of guzzle

Comment: @Doggo Thanks for your reply. I also managed the same.